# Linux Crontab Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, cron, segmentation-fault

For some reason, my crontab is giving me segmentation fault (core dumped) error when ever I attempt to access it using crontab -l or crontab -e.

Everything is fine if I access the root crontab or another users crontab but if I try to acccess mine either via the commands above or even as root using crontab -l -u [userid].

Until recently, this crontab has worked fine and I do not know of anything that has been installed recently.

I'm running RHE6, 2GB ram, 60Gb disk.

Comment: This might be a damaged `crontab` command, or a damaged filesystem, or some hardware problem. Can you, as root, view the existing crontabs with `ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs` and `cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<userid>`? If that works OK, run `rpm -V cronie` to verify the health of the `crontab` binary and other associated files. Also, check for any bad-looking messages in `dmesg` output.

Comment: What does happen if you try to open the user crontab as root: `crontab -u USER -l`?